# Is it possible to use d3.js drawn elements as Isotope components

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, jquery-isotope

Hi we are drawing certain rectangular shapes and with some info in it. Now I would like to use those shapes in different layout offered by isotope (jquery).js. Is it possible for me to do that ? I am left clueless after I searched for a while on the web. Any resources to learn if there are any alternate approaches. Thanks.

Comment: can you please be clear with ur question? may be you're missing something

Comment: Avinash, we need to draw some svg images using d3.js dynamically. Now we want to use those svg images in  isotope for layouts. Actually I am a total newbie to web. That is why my question may lack depth. Thanks for helping me anyways.

Comment: it's ok yaar .. we all are newbie's at some point of time :) I understood your question, but I felt like whether you'd like to do something else :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw them in separate container svg elements, then the can be positioned using normal css.

So you should be able to position them with isotope. If you give the svg elements class names / ids that are expected (the ones you set in the isotope config) by isotope.

D3 can also be used to generate divs not just svg. So if you're in need of simple shaps such as rectangles you might get away with just generating divs.

Note: This is a very old answer now, It appears that Isotope explicitly excludes svg (thanks Geraldo), I'd recommend using D3js for layout in full or html elements (for isotope) in this case.

Comment: Did not work for me applying isotope to svg elements like <rect class="node" width="2" height="2"/>. I use '.node' as item selector but noting happens.

Comment: Hi @geraldo I must admit it's been sometime since I last played with d3 and svg etc. I have a feeling perhaps css and therefore isotope might not be able to style all properties in svg, it'll probably be easiest to use divs.

Comment: It seems to me like Isotope even doesn't find svg nodes. I posted a question about that which includes a fiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624854/how-to-apply-isotope-to-svg-nodes

Comment: You're right @geraldo, I suppose my original answer was more general to the general question of integrating svg and javascript. I'll update my answer.