# How to apply isotope to svg nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, jquery-isotope

Because of a big amount of elements (>5000), I'd like to apply isotope to SVG and not to HTML nodes. The nodes are represented as:

```
<rect class="node" width="2" height="2"/>
```

I use '.node' as item selector but isotope doesn't seem to find the elements and nothing happens. Any hint if this could be possible or if the library can't be applied to SVG elements?

Here the test case: https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/bL25f73a/

Comment: Question not clear :( and your fiddle does not work.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show that with the same configuration applied to HTML nodes the library works as expected, but using SVG nodes does'nt do anything. Hope that makes the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a look at the Isotope source code, unfortunately it looks like it's explicitly excluding SVG.

```
  elems.forEach( function( elem ) {
    // check that elem is an actual element
    if ( !( elem instanceof HTMLElement ) ) {
      return;
    }
```

https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/blob/master/dist/isotope.pkgd.js#L653

Just to verify, I did `$("rect")[0] instanceof HTMLElement` and it's returning false.